# getenv + string in c and converting types

Tags: c

I want to add /home/username + "/path.png?5667!http-get:*:image/png:!!!!!" just as in Java. but in C

`name = malloc(strlen(hm)+strlen("/path.png?5667!http-get:*:image/png:!!!!!") + 2);`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
char *hm;
char *full;
hm = getenv("HOME");
full = malloc(strlen(hm)+strlen("/path.png?5667!http-get:*:image/png:!!!!!") + 2);
printf("name = %s\n",name);
```

I expect: `/home/username/path.png?5667!http-get:*:image/png:!!!!!"`

Comment: `malloc` allocates memory, but you still need to copy the string into `char *full;`.

Comment: `name` or `full`?...show actual code

Comment: The code makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be afraid to use str utilities. `man strcpy`, `man strcat`.
Here is what I think you want (Unclear from post):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int     main()
{
  char* home = getenv("HOME");
  char* add = "/path.png?5667!http-get:*:image/png:!!!!!";
  char* full = malloc(strlen(home) + strlen(add) + 1);
  strcpy(full, home);
  strcat(full, add);
  printf("Full = %s", full);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gives `warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]` for char* add, but works as expected